Laptop sometimes fails booting from sleep or hibernate, causing BSOD
Or maybe it fails to go into sleep/hibernate properly.
The problem
I've got this problem with my laptop (ThinkPad P53, Windows 10) where it gets stuck at boot after sleep or hibernate (problem is present with both sleep and hibernate). I don't know if it happens with normal shutdowns and boots since I rarely turn it off completely.
After getting stuck, I either have to wait for like 2 minutes before a BSOD appears, after which it will restart. Or I can press the power button to force it to shutdown and then start it back up.
Aside from this not being a nice process to go through when you want to start your laptop, I also have a problem with 'random' things breaking in the windows system or installed programs. This can very well be related to the system not properly booting or shutting down while trying to boot or not shutting down properly to begin with. That's why I want to find the cause of this booting issue. I have this laptop for 4 years now, and I don't remember a time when it didn't do this.
What I've found or haven't found:

I haven't found a pattern for this issue. There isn't an amount of times I can boot before this issue occurs, so it can happen twice in a row, or I can have 10 successful boots in a row. It also doesn't matter how long the laptop has been sleeping for, sometimes I switch from one class in school to another, (like 5 mins) and the laptop hangs at boot.

I also checked event viewer. I can see a trace of 'The previous system shutdown at [time] on [date] was unexpected. And indeed, before this message, there isn't an event that says system is entering sleep, so probably it just doesn't enter sleep properly.

Then I also calculated how many times it fails to boot on average, which is about every 6 or 7 boots, it fails. So I tried putting the laptop into sleep and booting it 20 times, but it didn't fail. So it doesn't seem to be related to the amount of sleeps/continues.


About the laptop
It's a ThinkPad P53 that I bought brand new a little over 4 years ago, windows 10 preinstalled. It's had this problem for as long as I can remember. One year ago, I reinstalled windows 10 (clean install, from a usb drive) hoping it would also fix this booting issue.

Finally, my guess would be that there is a program or driver preventing the system from going into sleep/hibernate, causing problems. But I don't know how to go from here. If there is anyone able to help, it'd be greatly appreciated. Also, if I forgot any information I'm happy to add it.

(Markdown formatting goes a long way in making content more efficient to digest, especially bulleted lists - this is essentially written in a letter format in lieu of a more efficiently digestible format). What BSOD is being populated? Is ti the same BSOD type every time? Did the laptop come with Win 10 preinstalled, was this an upgrade to Win10, or a clean install of WIn10? If WIn10 was ever clean installed or reset, were the CPU chipset drivers installed immediately upon exiting OOBE, prior to software, drivers, or Windows Updates (this is vital and a requirement that can't be skipped)?

Also check the main drive. hiberfil.sys, stored there, is where Windows serializes the OS state, and a bad drive could mess up that file.

Thanks for the replies. I did a clean install of windows 10 a year ago. Don't know when the CPU chipset drivers were installed, I just plugged the usb drive in, and let the installer do it's magic. Then after windows installed, I got the device specific drivers from lenovo vantage and lenovo system update. Also, I don't know what the BSOD says (I usually don't wait until it appears). But I know it can give some hints in the right direction, so I will be checking it from now on.

With what method can I check the main drive best?

@Wim (Please mention user in replies via @) Regardless of BSOD, if usure the CPU chipset driver was the first thing installed after clean installing, it's recommend to clean install again since it's vital CPU chipset drivers are installed first, especially with laptops. The OS itself, and other drivers and software, depend on the chipset drivers being installed first to properly function. Install order: Chipset, reboot, other CPU drivers, rebooting after each install, configure Windows Update to install third-party drivers, run WIndows Update, reboot when it needs to, and repeat.

(Cont'd...) Windows Update will install all drivers except CPU drivers since these are highly customized by the OEM for each machine. The only drivers that would need to be manually downloaded and installed from the OEM's support site would be for OEM specific applications/drivers (looking at the P53 driver download page, I'm unsure what those might be, but as an example, Alienware has an OSD driver to switch between integrated and discrete graphics, AlienFX drivers/software to control the keyboard backlighting and optical lights, etc.)
